# CMD IF EXIST evaluation time

Tags: cmd

I have a computer inside a windows domain that uses a mapped home drive I: and I have a logon script (via GPO) that is supposed to do something on that drive. From my observations I would guess that there seems to be some kind of race condition between the mapping and the start of the logon script:

Sometimes the script "finds" the mapped drive, when run, sometimes it doesn't. My approach is to repeat that test until the drive is finally mapped (or until we give up). So here's the code:

```
SET /A COUNT_CHECK_I=1
:LOOP_CHECK_I
IF NOT EXIST I:\ (
    ECHO Attempt %COUNT_CHECK_I%... >> %LOGFILE%
    SET /A COUNT_CHECK_I+=1
    IF %COUNT_CHECK_I% GEQ 10 (
        ECHO Giving up... >> %LOGFILE%
        EXIT /B 1
    ) ELSE (
        TIMEOUT /T 30
        GOTO :LOOP_CHECK_I
    )
)
...
```

(I increased the timeout for debugging.)

The logfile is written just as expected - one line every 30s. However, even though the mapped drive is definetely there, the script never becomes aware of this. If run manually, the script behaves completely normal as the IF evaluates to FALSE right away.

What's going on here and how could that goal - "Check, if a Drive exists, if not, wait a bit and check again." - be achieved?

Comment: Slightly different approach could be adding the mapping in your script if not found?  
you can try something like
    net use i: \\server\share

Comment: A problem with putting `NET USE` in the script is that it may require a plain-text password. Bad idea. How about using `NET USE >>"%LOGFILE%"` to see what drive mappings the script is seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try

```dos
set "foundI="
(for /l %%a in (1 1 10) do if not defined foundI (
    vol i: && ( set "foundI=1" ) || if %%a lss 10 ( 
        >&9 echo Attemp %%a failed ...
        timeout /t 2 
    ) else (
        >&9 echo Giving up ...
        exit /b 1
    )
)) >nul 2>nul 9>> %LOGFILE%
```

It just uses `vol i:` command to check the volume is available.